# Replicating SQL Group By, Having and Sum functionality in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation

Here is my sql query:

```
 select     tri.FINCODE, tri.YEAR_END, sum(qr.OP_INCOME) OP_INCOME, sum(qr.OP_EXPENSE) OP_EXPENSE, sum(qr.INT_COST) INT_COST, sum(qr.EBIT) EBIT, sum(qr.NOPAT) NOPAT, sum(qr.MINORITY_INTEREST_PL) MINORITY_INTEREST_PL
    from    fin_qtr_results  qr
    inner join fin_qtr_results tri
    on qr.FINCODE = tri.FINCODE and qr.DATE_END <= tri.YEAR_END and qr.DATE_END >= tri.YEAR_END - 99
    group by tri.FINCODE, tri.YEAR_END
    having count(*) = 4
```

It is basically a self join with a condition, then a group by and a having count(*) condition. I am trying to get trailing twelve month data.

Now I have a dataframe with the exact same structure at the table. I do not always have data for all quarters, hence when data is not available for 4 quarters, the TTM Sum should be NULL

fincode year_end op_income
1001    202303   100
1001    202306   200
1001    202309   300
1001    202312   400

How do I achieve this in Pandas.

I tried rolling sum, apply lambda but am just not getting how to do this.

This is the code from the response by AshhadDevLab, it works with a problem:

```
import pandas as pd
sql_data = {
    'FINCODE': [1001, 1001, 1001, 1001,1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1003, 1003, 1003, 1003,1003, 1003, 1003, 1003],
    'YEAR_END': [202103, 202203, 202206, 202209, 202303, 202306, 202309, 202312, 202103, 202106, 202109, 202112, 202203, 202206, 202209, 202212],
    'OP_INCOME': [5,10, 30, 70, 100, 200, 300, 400, 200, 150, 20, 40, 700, 200, 30, 60]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(sql_data)
df['YEAR_END'] = pd.to_datetime(df['YEAR_END'], format='%Y%m')
df_ttm = df.groupby('FINCODE').apply(lambda x: x.set_index('YEAR_END')['OP_INCOME'].rolling('365D').sum().reset_index())
df_ttm = df_ttm.reset_index(drop=False)[['FINCODE', 'YEAR_END', 'OP_INCOME']] #This Ungroups the dataframe
df_ttm.rename(columns={'OP_INCOME':'TTM_OP_INCOME'}, inplace=True)
df_ttm['YEAR_END'] = df_ttm['YEAR_END'].dt.strftime('%Y%m')

print(df_ttm)
```

This is the printed output:

```
    FINCODE YEAR_END  TTM_OP_INCOME
0      1001   202103            5.0
1      1001   202203           10.0
2      1001   202206           40.0
3      1001   202209          110.0
4      1001   202303          200.0
5      1001   202306          370.0
6      1001   202309          600.0
7      1001   202312         1000.0
8      1003   202103          200.0
9      1003   202106          350.0
10     1003   202109          370.0
11     1003   202112          410.0
12     1003   202203          910.0
13     1003   202206          960.0
14     1003   202209          970.0
15     1003   202212          990.0
```

As you can see the problem is that the sum happens even if data for exactly 4 quarters is not available. Output should be None if data for all 4 quarters (making up the trailing twelve months) is not available.

That is what the having count(*) in the SQL does.
Expected Output:

```
    FINCODE YEAR_END  TTM_OP_INCOME
0      1001   202103           None
1      1001   202203           None
2      1001   202206           None
3      1001   202209           None
4      1001   202303           None
5      1001   202306           None
6      1001   202309           None
7      1001   202312         1000.0
8      1003   202103           None
9      1003   202106           None
10     1003   202109           None
11     1003   202112          410.0
12     1003   202203          910.0
13     1003   202206          960.0
14     1003   202209          970.0
15     1003   202212          990.0
```

Comment: It would be better to provide a [mre] as python code to instantiate a pandas DataFrame and the matching expected output

Comment: I have tried to use the code submitted by @AshhadDevLab point out the problem I am facing.

Comment: what is the exact expected output?

Comment: I have updated the question with the new code and expected output

Comment: @QuantsBridge I have edited my code and this is as close as I can get.

Comment: @QuantsBridge I don't fully understand your output. I believe the rows 8/9/10 should be kept since all quarters are present for code 1003 and year 2021 (03/06/09/12). Same for year 2023 and code 1001 (rows 4/5/6/7).

Comment: For 1003, 202103: TTM value should be populated only if data for all 4 previous quarters is available i.e. data should be available for 202103, 202012, 202009 and 202006 for fincode 1003. This should be true for all TTM values.